# Spring boot でMethod not allowedエラー

Tags: java, spring

Spring bootで http://blog.rakugakibox.net/entry/2014/11/23/java_spring_boot_rest を参考にしてRest APIを作成しています。下記コントローラに対して、curlを使ってPOSTリクエストを送ると`Method now allowed`エラーが出てしまいます。

コントローラ

```
package controllers;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;

import models.HogeData;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/hoges")
public class HogeController {
    private static List<HogeData> store = new ArrayList<HogeData>();

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<HogeData> post(@ModelAttribute HogeData hogeData, UriComponentsBuilder builder){
        store.add(hogeData);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setLocation(builder.path("/hoges/{id}").buildAndExpand(store.size()).toUri());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(hogeData, headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<HogeData> getter(){
        return store;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public HogeData get(@PathVariable int id){
        return store.get(id - 1);
    }

}
```

curl

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json"        -d "integer=1"        -d "string=aaa"        -d "strings=AAA1" -d "strings=AAA2" -d "strings=AAA3"        http://localhost:8080/hoges
```

レスポンス

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Allow: HEAD, GET
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Mon, 26 Oct 2015 00:13:44 GMT

{"timestamp":1445818424033,"status":405,"error":"Method Not Allowed","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException","message":"Request method 'POST' not supported","path":"/hoges"}
```

実行環境
OS: Mac OS X El Captan
ビルド: Gradleで`gradle bootRun`を実行

コントローラでPOSTリクエストに対するメソッドは定義しているのでできるはずですがなぜかできません。なぜだかわかりますか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。

プロジェクトのパッケージ構造が間違っていてコントローラのクラスはスターティングポイントであるApplicationクラスのあるパッケージ配下に置く必要がありましたがそれができていませんでした。

```
src
    ├── main
    │   └── java
    │       └── restexample
    │           └── app
    │               ├── Application.java
    │               ├── controllers
    │               │   └── HogeController.java
    │               └── models
    │                   └── HogeData.java
    └── test
        └── java
```

上記のように構成を変更することで正しく呼び出せるようになりました。

Answer (score 0):

curlのリクエストがGETになっています。

```
-X POST
```

オプションを付与して呼び出すことでPOSTリクエストになります。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。`curl -i -H "Accept: application/json"        -d "integer=1"        -d "string=aaa"        -d "strings=AAA1" -d "strings=AAA2" -d "strings=AAA3"   -XPOST     http://localhost:8080/hoges`では同じエラーでできません。具体的にどのようなコマンドを打てばいいのかお教え頂けないでしょうか。